# kpsewhich doesn't find texmflocal files

Tags: texlive-2018, kpsewhich

I installed texlive 2018 on a CentOS7 linux machine. I'm not sure what I've missed, but `kpsewhich` is not finding my local sty files.

I installed them to my TEXMFLOCAL directory (`TEXMFLOCAL/tex/latex/package/package.sty`) and ran `mktexlsr`. The `*.sty` files do show up in the `TEXMFLOCAL/ls-R` file.

The files under `TEXMFLOCAL` are owned by me and readable by everyone.
The entire distribution is owned by me (which is why I didn't use `sudo`).

Here's the setup, using `mtpro2.sty` as an example.

The file mtpro2.sty exists as `/docs/tex/local/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty`

```
> which kpsewhich
/docs/tex/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich
> kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
/docs/tex/local
> grep mtpro2.sty /docs/tex/local/ls-R
mtpro2.sty
> kpsewhich mtpro2.sty
>

> kpsewhich --debug=2 mtpro2.sty
  kdebug:db:init(): using db file /docs/tex/local/ls-R.
  kdebug:db:init(): using db file /docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-config/ls-R.
  kdebug:db:init(): using db file /docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-var/ls-R.
  kdebug:db:init(): using db file /docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R.
  kdebug:/docs/tex/local/ls-R: 771 entries in 33 directories (0 hidden).
  kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 460 nonempty (0%); 771 entries,       average chain 1.7.
  kdebug:/docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-config/ls-R: 20 entries in 12 directories (0 hidden).
  kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 474 nonempty (0%); 791 entries, average chain 1.7.
  kdebug:/docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-var/ls-R: 148 entries in 35 directories (0 hidden).
  kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 591 nonempty (0%); 939 entries, average chain 1.6.
  kdebug:/docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-dist/ls-R: 173357 entries in 12640 directories (0 hidden).
  kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 55122 nonempty (86%); 174296 entries, average chain 3.2.
```

The relevant lines in ls-R are:

```
./tex/latex/mtpro2:
mtpro2.sty
omslbm.fd
umt2bb.fd
umt2hrb.fd
umt2mf.fd
umt2ms.fd
```

I have no TeX-related environment variables set.

Any ideas on what I've missed?

**EDIT** with info on texmf.cnf

I do have two texmf.cnf files:

```
> cd /doc/tex
> find ./ -name texmf.cnf
./distros/2018/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
./distros/2018/texmf.cnf
```

I think that is normal and the texmf-dist version is overridden with the single variable set in `./distros/2018/texmf.cnf` which has one uncommented line:

```
TEXMFLOCAL = /docs/tex/local
```

FWIW, I installed using a tl_profile, here it is:

```
selected_scheme scheme-full

TEXDIR /docs/tex/distros/2018
TEXMFLOCAL /docs/tex/local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var
binary_x86_64-linux 1
instopt_adjustpath 0
instopt_adjustrepo 1
instopt_letter 1
instopt_portable 0
instopt_write18_restricted 1
tlpdbopt_autobackup 1
tlpdbopt_backupdir tlpkg/backups
tlpdbopt_create_formats 1
tlpdbopt_desktop_integration 1
tlpdbopt_file_assocs 1
tlpdbopt_generate_updmap 0
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 1
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 1
tlpdbopt_post_code 1
tlpdbopt_sys_bin /usr/local/bin
tlpdbopt_sys_info /usr/local/share/info
tlpdbopt_sys_man /usr/local/share/man
tlpdbopt_w32_multi_user 1
```

and this commmand, given in `/docs/tex/distros/2018` (as myself):

```
./install-tl --profile /docs/tex/distros/tl.profile
```

And here are some relevant lines from the `install-tl.log`:

```
Settings:
  TEXDIR: "/docs/tex/distros/2018"
  TEXMFCONFIG: "~/.texlive2018/texmf-config"
  TEXMFHOME: "~/texmf"
  TEXMFLOCAL: "/docs/tex/local"
  TEXMFSYSCONFIG: "/docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-config"
  TEXMFSYSVAR: "/docs/tex/distros/2018/texmf-var"
  TEXMFVAR: "~/.texlive2018/texmf-var"
```

Comment: Remove the `ls-R` files in your local tree ...

Comment: I removed TEXMFLOCAL/ls-R but still get no result from kpsewhich. I don't see any ls-R in my home directory.

Comment: Just as a check, `find /docs/ -type f | grep mtpro2` does list the file right?

Comment: thanks. find /docs/ -type f | grep mtpro2 returns a lot of mtpro2 font files, but this is the first hit:
/docs/tex/local/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty

Comment: I got the distro from here, is this the right place? http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz

Comment: The setup seems fine, I've installed the same on (Ubuntu), and have no issues with local stuff in texmf-local, and I have a la-R file in it. So I cannot tell you what's wrong. Btw:  please add @username when you're answering someone, then that person gets an alert. Only diffence I have is that I used the standard location and name for my texmf-local. What is in the texmf.cnt file? (note there is more than one)

Comment: hi @daleif, thanks very much for looking at this. I added info on the texmf.cnf files and some about the installation process. I downloaded the install-tl-unx.tar.gz file, unzipped it and used the install-tl command with a profile (included above). After the install I moved my package files under the TEXMFLOCAL directory and ran mktexlsr.

Comment: for anyone spending time on this, I am sorry (thanks @daleif). My PATH was pointing to an old tex distribution and its binaries. I still have problems but kpsewhich isn't one of them. Sorry for all the noise and thanks for checking on the setup.